# Heatmaps: как форматировать ячейки тепловой карты?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, визуализация, seaborn

Мне нужно сделать "тепловую" карту из моего двумерного массива, который я получаю следующим образом:

```py
n = 7 #высота
m = 5 #ширина
TxPower = 20
AntGain = 10
PenetrationLoses = 0 #pow(10,12/10)
InterferenceMagrin = 3

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):
        if i == 3 and j == 2:
            a[i][j] = 180
        else:
            distance =  0.01 * math.sqrt(math.fabs(2 - j)* math.fabs(2 - j) + math.fabs(3 - i)*math.fabs(3 - i))
            PathLoses = 26 * math.log(2.4) + 22.7 + 36*(math.log(distance))
            lineBudget = TxPower + AntGain - PenetrationLoses - InterferenceMagrin - PathLoses
            a[i][j] = round(lineBudget)
```

Я получаю вот такой результат заполнения:

```
101.0 106.0 108.0 106.0 101.0 

110.0 118.0 122.0 118.0 110.0
 
118.0 135.0 147.0 135.0 118.0 

122.0 147.0 180.0 147.0 122.0 

118.0 135.0 147.0 135.0 118.0 

110.0 118.0 122.0 118.0 110.0 

101.0 106.0 108.0 106.0 101.0
```

Затем я пытаюсь отобразить этот массив в виде тепловой карты:

```py
ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (5,7))
sns.heatmap(pd.DataFrame(np.round(a)), annot=True, xticklabels= True, yticklabels= True, square=True)
```

Но в ячейках массива он отображает эти значения следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можете помочь разобраться, с чем это связано и как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Согласно документации [seaborn](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html#seaborn.heatmap), метод `.heatmap` имеет параметр форматирования:

> fmt : str, optional
> String formatting code to use when adding annotations.

Попробуйте добавить в `sns.heatmap()`

```
fmt='g'
```

для вывода целочисленного значения:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

или

```
fmt='d'
```

Comment: Спасибо большое